# Converting musical notes to WAV

Tags: c++, music

So, here is my code for converting musical notes stored in a text file to WAV. You can see an example of its output [here](https://gitlab.com/FlatAssembler/notestorawsoundconverter).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <map>

std::map<std::string,float> notes;
int sampleRate=44100;

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    notes["a"]=220;
    notes["as"]=233;
    notes["b"]=247;
    notes["C"]=262;
    notes["Cs"]=277;
    notes["D"]=293;
    notes["Ds"]=311;
    notes["E"]=329;
    notes["F"]=349;
    notes["Fs"]=370;
    notes["G"]=391;
    notes["Gs"]=415;
    notes["A"]=440;
    notes["As"]=466;
    notes["H"]=493;
    notes["C5"]=523;
    notes["Cs5"]=554;
    notes["D5"]=587;
    notes["Ds5"]=622;
    notes["E5"]=659;
    if (argc<2) {
        std::cerr<<"Please supply the text file with notes as an argument." <<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::ifstream input(argv[1]);
    if (argc>2)
        sampleRate=atoi(argv[2]);
    if (!input)
    {
        std::cerr<<"Can't open \"" <<argv[1] <<"\" for reading!" <<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *wav=std::fopen("output.wav","wb");
    if (!wav) {
        std::cerr <<"Can't open \"output.wav\" for output!" <<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    bool isLittleEndian;
    int testNumber=0x10;
    std::fwrite(&testNumber,sizeof(int),1,wav);
    std::fclose(wav);
    wav=std::fopen("output.wav","rb");
    char testCharacter=0;
    std::fread(&testCharacter,1,1,wav);
    std::fclose(wav);
    if (testCharacter==0x10) //The logic is: if the C library uses big endian for writing binary files, now "testCharacter" will still contain 0.
        isLittleEndian=true;
    else
        isLittleEndian=false;
    wav=std::fopen("output.wav","wb");
    if (isLittleEndian)
        std::fprintf(wav,"RIFF"); //ASCII for 0x52494646, the magic number that WAV files start with. 
    else
        std::fprintf(wav,"RIFX"); //Big endian WAV file starts with magic number 0x52494658, or, in ASCII, "RIFX". 
    int32_t ChunkSize=36+8*sampleRate*2;
    std::fwrite(&ChunkSize,4,1,wav);
    std::fprintf(wav,"WAVEfmt "); //The beginning of the header.
    int32_t Subchunk1Size=16; //PCM header is always 16 bytes.
    std::fwrite(&Subchunk1Size,4,1,wav);
    int16_t AudioFormat=1; //PCM format.
    std::fwrite(&AudioFormat,2,1,wav);
    int16_t NumChannels=1; //MONO audio.
    std::fwrite(&NumChannels,2,1,wav);
    int32_t SampleRate=sampleRate;
    std::fwrite(&SampleRate,4,1,wav);
    int32_t ByteRate=2*sampleRate; //Since we are using 16 bits per sample, and "sampleRate" samples per second.
    std::fwrite(&ByteRate,4,1,wav);
    int16_t BlockAlign=2; //Each block is two bytes.
    std::fwrite(&BlockAlign,2,1,wav);
    int16_t BitsPerSample=16;
    std::fwrite(&BitsPerSample,2,1,wav);
    std::fprintf(wav,"data");
    while (!input.eof()) {
        std::string currentNote;
        input >>currentNote;
        if (currentNote.length()==0) break;
        std::string durationString="";
        int i=0;
        while ((currentNote[i]>='0' && currentNote[i]<='9') || currentNote[i]=='.')
        {
            durationString+=currentNote.substr(i,1);
            i++;
        }
        std::cerr <<"Read note name \"" <<currentNote <<"\", the duration string is: " <<durationString <<std::endl;
        int noteDuration=3*sampleRate/std::stof(durationString);
        std::string fullNoteName=currentNote.substr(i);
        std::cerr <<"Playing note \"" <<fullNoteName <<"\" for " <<noteDuration <<" samples." <<std::endl;
        for (int i=0; i<noteDuration; i++) {
            float currentFrequency=notes[fullNoteName];
            float baseFrequency=sin(2*M_PI*currentFrequency*i/sampleRate)*16384;
            float secondHarmony=sin(2*M_PI*2*currentFrequency*i/sampleRate+M_PI/4)*4096;
            float thirdHarmony=sin(2*M_PI*3*currentFrequency*i/sampleRate+M_PI/2)*1024;
            float fourthHarmony=sin(2*M_PI*4*currentFrequency*i/sampleRate+M_PI/2)*512;
            float currentAmplitude=(baseFrequency+secondHarmony+thirdHarmony+fourthHarmony)*std::exp(-(float)(2*i+sampleRate)/(sampleRate)); //Attenuation. 
            int16_t numberToBeWritten=(fullNoteName=="P")?(0):(currentAmplitude);
            numberToBeWritten+=std::rand()%256-128; //A bit of noise makes it sound better.
            std::fwrite(&numberToBeWritten,2,1,wav);
        }
    }
    std::fclose(wav);
}
```

So, what do you think about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Don't put everything in `main`.
- Prefer an initializer list map constructor:

  ```
  std::map<std::string,float> notes {
      {"a", 220},
      {"as", 233},
      ....
  };
  ```
- Testing endianness is kinda convoluted. Consider `htons`: network byte order is big endian.

  ```
  bool is_little_endian()
  {
      uint16_t x = 0x0055;
      uint16_t y = htons(x);
      return x != y;
  }
  ```
- `while (!inpit.eof())` [is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5605159/3403834).
- It is very unclear how the input file is formatted. In any case, manual testing for numbers and decimal points is likely unnecessary and error prone. `std::strtof` will do everything you want with the way less effort and better reliability.
- I am not that versed in music to figure out what is going on with those harmonies. It looks suspicious that the phase shift is \$\dfrac{\pi}{4}\$ for the second harmony, and \$\dfrac{\pi}{2}\$ for the third and fourth. Also, the amplitudes of those harmonies look like magic numbers.